# Tag request: product-key

Tags: discussion, tags

Because a product key or a Certificate of Authenticity was more common with old operating systems or software, the tag [product-key](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-key) would be a good key to add. The excerpt it could have:

> A product key helps prevent piracy of software. Use if you have a question about product keys and old OS's or software.

or

> For questions asking about product keys and old operating systems or software.

Comment: Are you referring to [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6492/278)?

Comment: It was what I wanted to use it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up Stephen Kitts comment, I think a tag that covers copy protection schemes/keys is more apropriate, as it may be useful not only for MS-stuff, but anything from installation keys to page numbers on manuals asked for in a game.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a useful tag to have. However, I'd be tempted to call the tag [license-key](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license-key) instead... though I'm not sure why. I have a gut feeling that it'll be applicable to more questions, but I can't think of any examples.

Comment: I can't think of any examples, either, but [tag:license-key] might be better then [tag:product-key].

Comment: I think it's way too restrictive as licence or product key. Make it about copy protection, then we're geting something useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure about that - MS introduced product keys with Windows 95, started to work with them in earnest with Windows 98 by ~2000. This is somehow on the borderline of what I would consider "retro".

A product key program that was really working required an internet connection and online activation. Only after that was feasible, product keys started to make some sense. And the Internet as a widely available commodity is definitely non-retro, IMHO.

Comment: If this was about dongles, then it would be retro ;-).